# psql copy running out of tmp space on what host?

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I have a python process that forks a psql command.  The command connects to the remote database and COPY's into a local psql which reads the data.  Here's the command vastly simplified and broken into several lines for readability.:

```
psql --quiet -X --quiet 
    --command='\pset tuples_only'
    --command='\copy (TABLE QUERY) to program
        \'psql "--command=copy TABLE from stdin with (format binary)"
        postgresql://apolloqa:Apollo123@LOCALHOST:PORT/LOCAL_DB\' 
    with (format binary)' postgresql://REMOTE_USER:REMOTE_PASS@REMOTE_HOST:PORT/REMOTE_DB
```

(The quotes may be wrong after editing it from my logs, but it works on other machines, and it's not germane to my question.)  The logs show:

```
Dec 20 03:06:51 LOCAL_HOST copying_server.sh[2788715]: PSQL STDOUT:
Dec 20 03:06:51 LOCAL_HOST copying_server.sh[2788715]: COPY 1310
Dec 20 03:06:51 LOCAL_HOST copying_server.sh[2788715]: COPY 29285588
Dec 20 03:06:51 LOCAL_HOST copying_server.sh[2788715]:
Dec 20 03:06:51 LOCAL_HOST copying_server.sh[2788715]: PSQL STDERR:
Dec 20 03:06:51 LOCAL_HOST copying_server.sh[2788715]: ERROR:  could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp122309.3": No space left on device
Dec 20 03:06:51 LOCAL_HOST db_copy_server.sh[2788715]: ERROR:  COPY file signature not recognized
```

The psql breaks because of no disk space.  But, which host ran out of disk space?  Local or remote host?  When I look at my local host, it has plenty of space.  So I doubt it's a local problem, but I cannot go onto the remote machine to see how much space it has.

I want to make sure it's not on my local host, before going to the admins for the remote host and remote database.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would be what ever host the logs are coming from.

Comment: " it's not germane to my question"  It is germane to me *understanding* your question.

Comment: Use postgres_fdw.